# How to use materialized paths to find documents in Mongo with MongoMapper?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

We want to search for documents using [materialized paths](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) against Mongo using MongoMapper.

How can we do this? Do we pass in the regular expression like `:path => /path_we_want/`?

We're on MongoMapper 0.12 and Mongo 2.2.

Comment: Have you "materialized" the documents to a `path` field (as a string)? Assuming so, it's just a regular expression ..., nothing fancy.

Comment: Yes, the :path attribute is actually an array of strings, so something like this: ['/path1/prodct1', '/path2/product2']. Does your answer still apply? If so, could you please add an answer so we can credit you?

Comment: The materialized path is normally just a single string. You'd need to make sure your query was operating on an array.

Comment: What do you mean by making sure it's operating on an array? Assume the path we want to search for is "/path1/cat2" and the array name is :categories. How would the query look different for an array vs a string?